# Position a <div> into another <div>

Tags: html, position

im just trying to do a normal Navigation but i seem to fail at it since i haven't done something like that in a long time. So here is what i got:

```
<div id="Top">
<div id="Navi">&nbsp;
<div class="Link">
<a href="index.php?s=link1">link1</a>
</div>
<div class="Link">
<a href="index.php?s=link2">link2</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and:

```
#Top {
width:100%;
min-height:100px;
height:15%;
max-height:200px;
background-color:#C6E466;
border-bottom-width:2px;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:#4E6011;
position:relative;
}
#Navi {
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:-1px;
left:-5px;
}
.Link {
height:20px;
margin-left:10px;
min-width:150px;
width:10%;
max-width:200px;
float:left;
background-color:#121212;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

I just want to have:
- a complete header at the Top, which is #Top, convering the whole area at the top from left to right (width:100%).
- In the #Top header i want to display some Links done via #Navi. However i want to display #Navi in the bottom right corner of #Top. So i figured i would do #Top to position relative and #Navi position:absolute, but it doesnt work.
- Then i wanted the link color to be white, but somehow it doesnt work - why?
- Why do i need to use   which i think is not cool? Without using   the complete #Navi div wouldn't show up!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try giving #Navi
bottom:0px and right:0px;

Comment: you also have to remove the `top:-1px` and `left:-5px` you have for it in the Q.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Top {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    height:15%;
    max-height:200px;
    background-color:#C6E466;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#4E6011;
    position:relative;
}
#Navi {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.Link {
    height:20px;
    margin-left:10px;
    min-width:150px;
    width:10%;
    max-width:200px;
    background-color:#121212;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what are you trying, but here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/4JdmH/

```
<div id="Top">
    <div id="Navi">
        <div class="Link">
            <a href="index.php?s=link1">link1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Link">
            <a href="index.php?s=link2">link2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</div>


#Top {
width:100%;
min-height:100px;
height:15%;
max-height:200px;
background-color:#C6E466;
border-bottom: 2px solid #4E6011;
position:relative;
}
#Navi {
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
}
.Link {
height:20px;
margin-left:10px;
min-width:150px;
width:10%;
max-width:200px;
float:left;
background-color:#121212;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
.clr {
    clear: both;
}
```